# NSMutableURLRequest and JSON - How would I finish this connection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, api, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to fetch data from an api and I have this code:

```
// create the URL we'd like to query
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.1/reports"];
NSString *token = auth.accessToken;
NSMutableURLRequest *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
[myURL addValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authentication"];

// we'll receive raw data so we'll create an NSData Object with it
@@@@@@
How would I complete this step? So far I have 
    NSData *myData = 
@@@@@@

// now we'll parse our data using NSJSONSerialization
id myJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

// typecast an array and list its contents
NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)myJSON;

NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray);
```

How would I connect on the 9th line?

Comment: Have a look at `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:]`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are putting all this code in one place (making a *synchronous* network request).  This is typically a bad idea.  You should put the first part (creating and starting the request) in one place, and put the parsing code in a separate method / block that gets called once the request is completed.  (This is called an *asynchronous* network request.)

You should take a look at `+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`.  You can pass your NSURLRequest in here, and then specify the completion (parsing, etc.) in the completion handler.  It will give you the NSData object you're looking for - [see documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest%3aqueue%3acompletionHandler%3a).

If you have more than a handful of network connections, this can get unwieldy.  You may want to look at a third party library like [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/), which can manage much of the tedious stuff for you, and let you focus on calling a URL, and parsing the response.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
NSData *myData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:myURL returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

This is a synchronous call. I'll suggest always using asynchronous webcalls is a good way.